# Gnome TopBar icons of "stay running" apps like Teams, Discord

Tags: debian, ubuntu, gnome

I have moved from Ubuntu to Debian, and I am missing a feature. There are apps like *Teams*, *Discord*, *JetBrains ToolBox*... which do not stop when closed, when the user closes them. They still run in the background. If these apps run in the background, I could saw icons on the topbar on Ubuntu. Unfortunatelym this does not happens in Debian.

Is there some way to that allow this behavior:
[image]

Icons of apps in topbar *(Ubuntu)*:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GNOME 3.26, GNOME removed system tray icons to the dismay of many. Like many things in linux however, there is always a community keeping it alive. I think [Tray Icons: Reloaded](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2890/tray-icons-reloaded/) is what you are looking for from a quick search.

Comment: That is, what i have been looking for. Thanks